# Stackpromo's SSL error

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2017

The stackoverflow.blog post links to `https://stackpromos.com/` ([link](https://stackpromos.com/)) which serves a certificate for `*.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: The blog post was fixed by linking to the http version instead.

Answer (score 14):

This was [reported on MSE already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304343/stackpromos-com-https-cert-is-invalid) with this answer from [hairboat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165581/hairboat):

> My bad.
>
> Word on the street is stackpromos.com probably isn't supposed to have
>   a valid cert, but I linked it in [the blog
>   post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/)
>   as https out of habit. Will fix as soon as I can get the blog post
>   edited!

<s>Give it 6 to 8 weeks ...</s>

Now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

> [**Update**: Fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/304344/2)

Comment: ah, dammit, I searched stackoverflow meta, forgot to check SE meta.

Comment: No problem, you are allowed to post bugs on your own site meta. Leave it to the MSE lurkers to bring over content or link to cross-site dupes.

Comment: So close this question as a duplicate?  Oh wait you can't since it's on meta.se :|

Comment: @rogerdpack I already flagged for a mod to tag this status-completed. That should do.

Comment: To be clear, the blog post is fixed... not the SSL cert. That's still pending with no ETA at the moment.